# React JS application to Google Play?

Tags: reactjs, google-play, apk

I made an app on React JS. This is SPA. The application is optimized for mobile phones, it can also be saved as a PWA application from a browser on a mobile phone.
Is it possible to convert this app to .apk for uploading to google play? How to do it?
My application Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chatgpt.ai.chatbot
Thank you!

Comment: No. You can't change PWA to .apk or any mobile App.

Comment: PWA is Progressive Web App. It needs web browser to run. Normal mobile app can run themselves.

Comment: but what can you say about https://www.pwabuilder.com/ for example?

Comment: I can say one thing. Do not believe everything you heard from internet. That includes me. Do more research. If you want to write mobile application, I suggest `React Native` which is upgrade version of `React`.

Comment: Checkout this https://developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-in-play#0

Comment: Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chatgpt.ai.chatbot this is my application